# eclipse search and replace with wildcard

Tags: regex, eclipse, wildcard, replace

I am trying to remove all occurances of **`id="someId"`** where someId is different in every case. I have tried to use this syntax: **`(id="\w+\"\(\))`** because it's used in similar situations by other posters. But I don't understand the syntax and of course it doesn't work.

Could someone tell me why this syntax is incorrect and maybe point me to a resource that explains the syntax?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check "Regular expressions" check box.
The expression is

```
id\s*=\s*"[^"]+"
```

`\s*` means *space*, `*` means *zero or more*

`[^"]` means *anything but quote*, `+` means *one or more*

To capture the string use `"([^"]+)"` and `$1` in the *replace with* field.

More info at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html